# The stamp xxx of location BLU is marked as inactive and cannot be updated

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, app-service-environment

I'm trying to restart web application deployed to service plan of my app service environment

I've got an error

Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName myrg -Name webappname

```
Restart-AzureRmWebApp : The stamp asename of location BLU is marked as inactive and cannot be updated.
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Restart-AzureRmWebApp], CloudException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.RestartAzureWebAppCmdlet
```

What is this error mean?

Comment: did you solve this yourself?